# Flex: CSS style. Can I use the IDs ? Or should I add the styleName attribute?

Tags: css, apache-flex

I'm using a CSS file to style my flex application.
can I use components IDs to change their style from the CSS file ?

Or I should add the styleName attribute for each element ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Flex 3 you can't use the ID (#) selector. This is supposedly added in Flex 4, but I haven't had the opportunity to try it out yet to see how well it works.

Flex also doesn't support combinator selectors.

Answer (score 0):

There's also [F*CSS](http://fcss.flashartofwar.com/) which supposedly adds pretty much functionality regarding CSS to Flash (and I guess Flex as well). Haven't actually worked with it yet, but the demonstration seems easy and solid enough. If you're willing to experiment you could give it a try.